# Can we use dataflow Streaming Job for table to table load?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

here, we have a source table that is in append mode loaded from pubsub via streaming-dataflow now I want to load that data to the target table by taking joins with another lookup table, using streaming Dataflow in upsert mode how to do that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do not ask **is it possible** types of questions. For almost any question the answer could be yes or no. To get a useful answer, you must clearly define the problem and provide details. Please read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: that is still yes/no question! :o)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining data in apache beam / cloud dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692975/joining-data-in-apache-beam-cloud-dataflow)

Comment: This is  possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692975/joining-data-in-apache-beam-cloud-dataflow